# Serving static files in an HTTP server

Tags: http, go, server, assets

I'm using golang as the backend for a medium-sized web app which has a few pages and a lot of CSS and javascript in different folders, I'm trying to serve the website using golang but only the index file loads , the other pages, javascript, CSS doest load. since my HTML files, all are different from each other I'm not using templates

here is the file structure

```
-static 
    -assets
        -css(folder with subfolders)
        -js(folder with subfolders)
    -pages (folder with differnt html pages)
         -signup.html
         -dashboard.html
    -index.html
    -register_bundle.js
-main.go
```

```
func handlerequests (){
 myRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
 myRouter.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static")))
 myRouter.HandleFunc("/transaction", transactionHandler)
 log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080",myRouter))
}
```

my HTML files have links like these, (showing index.html)

```
<!-- CSS Files -->
  <link href="./assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="./assets/css/paper-dashboard.css?v=2.1.1" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--JS files -->
  <script src="./assets/demo/demo.js"></script>
  <!--Main Script file for the page  -->
  <script src="./register_bundle.js"></script>
```

errors shown here

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try using absolute paths in the html. i.e. `"/assets...` instead of `"./assets...`, same with the register js file.

Comment: i tried that...but didnt work

Comment: did you try removing the `./` altogether?

Comment: yes, removed "./ " from everywhere, here is how the links look like now     
    <script src="/assets/js/core/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/plugins/moment.min.js"></script>

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache and then try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is browser cannot find those JS and CSS files.

```
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))
    MUXRouter.Handle("/", fs)
    MUXRouter.PathPrefix("/assets/").Handler(fs)
    MUXRouter.PathPrefix("/pages/").Handler(fs)
    MUXRouter.Handle("/register_bundle.js", fs)
```

That way a GET request to `http://[host]:[port]/css/style.css` will return style.css from the relative `./static/css/` directory. The above code is working in my sample program.

Comment: When you're just giving reference to some link, do it in comments and try not to use the answer section for that. If you still want to answer it and refrain from using comments, then an elaborate version might help. Also, do remember that links might get broken in future, so you should take the relevant parts from the references and add it with the answer so that it remains meaningful even after the link's broken.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
gor:= mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)

fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))
gor.PathPrefix("/transaction").Handler(fs)
```

it probably should work if it doesnt just try reading documentation for http.FileServer

Answer (score 1):

did you try serving a handler fot your resources folder?

```
sdir := "/resources/"
myRouter.PathPrefix(sdir).Handler(http.StripPrefix(sdir, http.FileServer(http.Dir("."+sdir))))
```

this allow you to access the foloder as a subdomain.

Comment: here instead of /resources/ i should use /static/ right?

Comment: if your file is "/assets/js/core/popper.min.js" you should use "assets" an the .exe/.go should be in tyhe same folder that assets folder
i think you have something like
-main.go
-assets/js/
-assets/css/
but if you have 
-main.go
-static/assets/js/
-static/assets/css/
yes you should use "/static/"

Comment: the assets folder is inside the static folder. so the file location is actually /static/assets/js/core/popper.min.js relative to main.go file and I'm serving the static folder with http.FileServer method. so should i create another method for each subfolder?

Comment: then you should use "/static/" but remember:
everything inside static folder will be public so be careful if you have something you dont want to be accesible from internet.